# How to disable images from payment module

Tags: magento-2.1

I have installed "online payment module". 
https://github.com/dotpay/magento2-payment

The entire store displays very large icons of this payment company which it does not need.

Any one know how can I delete this images ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The extension writer has embedded the image into the source code so the only way to remove it is to edit the source files.
So you need to edit two files:

```
view/adminhtml/templates/info/info.phtml
view/frontend/templates/info/info.phtml
```

and delete the line

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw....." />
```

Alternatively if you want the image to appear but be much smaller add a style to tag the image:

```
<img style="width:20px" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw....." />
```

Comment: @ andyredfern I have delete this line from info.phtml and then php bin/magento setup:upgrade and deploy and cache:flush and still this logo is displayed. Any solution ?

Comment: There are no further references to those images in the source code. There is a place where the accepted cards image is calling a saved value. Is there admin form where you can update the cards accepted image - perhaps that is set to this default image?

Comment: in the backend  can only set options "show logo payments in the basket"

Comment: I assume changing that setting does make any difference to anything you can see?

Most likely possibility is that your changed and uploaded code is not appearing. I would suggest adding a hidden HTML comment to the frontend  info template and see if it appears. If not that you can assume you are not clearing  the cache or completing the code change upload.